# VSCode 'default dark' theme doesn't automatically defaults the matplotlib style to 'dark_background'

Tags: matplotlib, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

---

#### ***Summary***

When figure is drawn with `matplotlib` using VSCode Jupyter Notebook, the figure is rendered in light theme even when the VSCode theme is dark. By my understanding, this [issue was resolved](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/3230) and the VSCode is supposed to default the `matplotlib` figures to `dark_background` when the VSCode theme is default dark.

What am I doing wrong?

---

I am fairly new to this whole data science and machine learning scene, and up till now I have been using Jupyter Notebook (and sometimes Jupyter Lab) for all my coding needs. However, the code completion in Jupyter Notebook leaves something to be desired, and so began my search for alternatives to Jupyter Notebook.

I recently discovered that VSCode supports the use of [Jupyter Notebook natively](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support) and after installing python extension, I was able to create new and open previously saved `.ipynb` files and every thing works great (especially the *IntelliSense*).

There is, however, one issue which is somewhat a nuisance. My theme for VSCode is default dark, and the figures produced by `matplotlib` are in light theme.

[image: using matplotlib in VSCode .ipynb]

I know I can use following code to render the figures in dark mode:

```py
from matplotlib import style
style.use('dark_background')
```

But on GitHub, this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/pull/3230) has already been addressed so that when the VSCode is in dark mode, then the VSCode will automatically default the `matplotlib` style to `dark_background`. However I am not experiencing this automation.

Is there some setting that I have failed to configure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some searching I found this solution:
In settings (via `ctrl+,`) search for
`jupyter run startup commands`

edit the json to:

```
    "jupyter.runStartupCommands": [
        "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt",
        "plt.style.use('dark_background')"
    ]
```

Then, restart your kernel.

Note, that somehow only using `matplotlib.style.use('dark_background')` does not yet fully work out, since some part gets overwritten on loading `pyplot` in the notebook it seems.

Comment: The style doesn't have to be global, you may override it import time in the single notebooks.

Answer (score 11):

On macOS with VS version 1.63.2 I found that enabling the following setting did the trick:

[image]

Comment: On Linux with 1.64.2 this wasn't enough, I had to give the style directive as in the accepted answer.

Comment: You should click `restart` button to restart the jupyter kernel to take it effective.

Comment: On Windows, I am able to change the setting similar to the solution for mac. Then restart the kernel.

Comment: I spent an entire day looking for this!! Thank you :)