# VS Code Jupyter Notebook Graphs Display Transparently

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I've recently downloaded VSCode and used it with Python and am having problems with the transparency of Matplotlib plots.

[image]

As you can see the, the figure element of the matplot graph is transparent, making the axes difficult to see.

Now when I go to look to other questions along similar lines it seems as though most people have the opposite problem ! For them, the white background appears when they don't want it too i.e [the figure isn't being transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61567100/vscode-default-dark-theme-doesnt-automatically-defaults-the-matplotlib-style). I tried using the approach outlined here - setting the default matplotlib style to white background - but this did not work.

This was a known problem back in 2019, but all the github threads on the issues declare it resolved. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/2904

I am using the atom theme here (which has a different background colour), but the problem persists even when restarted using the default settings, making me think something else is afoot.

I am on a mac, using a python installation from anaconda.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems I hadn't installed the correct jupyter rendering package. Normally, this downloads alongside the base package (it seems I was given a mild slap by the hand of chance) but just installing it separately solved the problem.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7470

(At the bottom)

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why vscode is doing this. However, the way I found to fix the issue is by explicitly setting the style context you want matplotlib to use in the plots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with plt.style.context('default'):
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(...)
   // your code in here
```